# Change the height of jWizard

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwizard

Can I change the height of the [jWizard jQuery plugin](https://github.com/dominicbarnes/jWizard)?

Comment: Can we please get a link to this plugin?

Comment: Sure. I did a edit to my question. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse u can, u will have to edit jWizard.base.css

search for .jw-steps-wrap in jWizard.base.css it will already have a height of 15em u can change it to ur desired value :)

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant way, is to overwrite the css - Class within the specific html-file (instead of changing the default class):

For instance use this in your html header:

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
   @import "./css/JWizard.base.css";

   .jw-steps-wrap {
        height: 250px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: .5em;
    }               

</style>
```

works like a charm!